# Prevent the default action when using jQuery for Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to prevent the default action when submitting a form with ajax but I believe I have my code wrong as the page seems to do a 'refresh' and the form clears but nothing is sent to the database. I tried adding the link to the php processing script in the 'action' part of the form and it does submit fine to the database so the problem seems to be with my jQuery code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    $("#rpack_add_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('<?php echo BASE_URL?>/core/addrpack.php.php', $("#rpack_add_form").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#ajaxResult').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My form code:

```
<div id="rpacks_admin" style="display: none;">
<h5>Add A New Recovery Pack</h5>
    <form id="rpack_add_form" class='small_form' name='rpack_add_form' action='' method='post'>
        Contract:
        <select id="contract_select" name="contract" onchange="showContract(this)">
            <option value='0'>Select Contract</option>
                <?php 
                $sth = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `contracts`");
                while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    echo '<option value='.$row['contracts_id'].'>'.$row['contracts_name'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
        </select>
            <div id="contract1" class="admin_box">
                Prefix: <input name='prefix' type='text' id='prefix'><br />
                Number: <input name='number' type='text' id='number'><br />
                Suffix: <input name='suffix' type='text' id='suffix'><br />
            </div>
            <div id="contract2" class="admin_box">
                <p>Sapce for content</p>
            </div>
            <div id="contract3" class="admin_box">
                <p>Sapce for contentrm</p>
            </div>
        Received:
            <select id="select_receive" name="received" onchange="showLocation(this)">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </select><br />
        <div id="location_box" style="display: none; padding-top: 5px;">Location: <input name='location' type='text' id='location'></div>
        <input class='button' type=submit value='Add' name='add_rpack'>            
    </form>
<a class='hide_div' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='hideRdiscDiv()'>Close</a>
```

and my PHP if needed

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            include_once 'config.php';
            include_once 'connect.php';
            include_once 'bcrypt.php';
            $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
            $number = $_POST['number'];
            $suffix = $_POST['suffix'];
            $contract = $_POST['contract'];
            $received = $_POST['received'];
            $location = $_POST['location'];

            //Check if password and username has been submitted then add to DB
            if (empty ($number))
            {
                echo "You need to enter a recovery pack number";
            }else
            {
                $sth = "INSERT INTO `rpacks` (rpacks_prefix, rpacks_number, rpacks_suffix, rpacks_contract, rpacks_receive, rpacks_location) VALUES (:prefix, :number, :suffix, :contract, :received, :location)";
                $q = $conn->prepare($sth);
                $q->execute(array(':prefix'=>$prefix,':number'=>$number,':suffix'=>$suffix,':contract'=>$contract, ':received'=>$received, ':location'=>$location));
                echo "Added";
            }
```

Comment: You need to return false from your javascript function.

Comment: Just wondering what e.preventDefault(); inside ready callback function is supposed to do?

Comment: you don't normally _// do other stuff for a valid form_ inside the submit handler. You define rules for that http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: You seem to be preventing the default of the ready event on the document, this is not what you want. You need to find a way to handle the submit event of the form and then preventDefault. What is that .validate? some custom event? a plugin?

Comment: @cernunnos, it's a jQuery plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Comment: @DerekHenderson this plugin doesn't provide a proper event reference on the submit handler? looking at the API i would expect the plugin captures the submit event and prevents the default behavior by itself, especially considering the usual quality of jquery official stuff. Returning false is rarely a good approach to stop default behavior.

Comment: @cernunnos, I agree with you about `return false;`. I only just discovered the plugin when I Googled for it in response to this question, and I saw no mechanism for referencing the event, but I may very well have missed something.  Personally, I can't see the point in using a plugin for validation, but I tried to shape my answer to what was being supplied in the question.

Comment: @cernunnos, dig and ye shall find!  A closer inspection of the docs yielded a much better answer.

Comment: @DerekHenderson i though so :D jquery split the "return false" behavior in 3 methods for a reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.validate()` object has a `sendForm` parameter.  It is set to `true` by default, but you need to set it to `false`, as in the code below, to prevent the form from being submitted:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rpack_add_form').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('<?php echo BASE_URL?>/core/addrpack.php.php', $('#rpack_add_form').serialize(), function (data) {
                $('#ajaxResult').html(data);
            });
        },
        sendForm: false
    });
});
```

You can [reference the docs](https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate#readme) for more info.